# Output data from DataTables within DataSet

Tags: c#, datatables, dataset

I currently accessing a database using multiple queries and storing the results from the queries into DatatTables. I decided since I'm using multiple DataTables to store them inside a DataSet.

I can see that data is inside the DataTables when I print them out. However when I try to access them from the DataSet to print out the data, I get nothing back; it is empty.

```
string querytest1  = "SELECT * FROM test1";
string querytest2  = "SELECT * FROM test2";
string querytest3  = "SELECT * FROM test3";

using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)){

     OleDbCommand commandtest1 = new OleDbCommand(querytest1 , connection);
     OleDbCommand commandtest2 = new OleDbCommand(querytest2 , connection);
     OleDbCommand commandtest3  = new OleDbCommand(querytest3 , connection);

     connection.Open();

     DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

     OleDbDataAdapter dataAdaptertest1  = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandResults);
     OleDbDataAdapter dataAdaptertest2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandResults);
     OleDbDataAdapter dataAdaptertest3  = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandProjects);

      DataTable dataTabletest1  = new DataTable();
      DataTable dataTabletest2 = new DataTable();
      DataTable dataTabletest3  = new DataTable();

       dataAdaptertest1.Fill(dataTabletest1 );
       dataAdaptertest2.Fill(dataTabletest2 );
       dataAdaptertest3.Fill(dataTabletest3 );

       dataTabletest1  = dataSet.Tables.Add("test1 ");
       dataTabletest2  = dataSet.Tables.Add("test2 ");
       dataTabletest3  = dataSet.Tables.Add("test3 ");

        Console.WriteLine("DataSet has {0} DataTables \n", dataSet.Tables.Count);

        foreach (DataTable objDt in dataSet.Tables)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", objDt.TableName);

        return dataSet;
```

Expected behaviour: is to be able to access a DataTable from the DataSet and print out the data.

Example: Print out the contents in Test1

The code is redundant. I just don't know a better way to do this.

Comment: Why do you need a dataset for this? You can just create an array of table names `["test1","test2","test3"]` and then open connection and use a loop to get the results like `OledbAdapter oa = new OledbAdapter(command)` and `Datatable tb = new Datatable(); oa.Fill(tb); print(tb)`  write a print function which loops through columns and displays it to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need three adapters to fill a DataSet with the results from three commands.

You can simply write:

```
string query1 = "SELECT * FROM test1";
string query2 = "SELECT * FROM test2";
string query3 = "SELECT * FROM test3";
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)){

     connection.Open();

     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q1, connection);
     OleDbDataAdapter da  = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(ds, "Test1");
     cmd.CommandText = q2;
     da  = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(ds, "Test2");
     cmd.CommandText = q3;
     da  = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(ds, "Test3");
}
Console.WriteLine("DataSet has {0} DataTables \n", ds.Tables.Count);
    foreach (DataTable objDt in ds.Tables)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", objDt.TableName);
```

The trick is filling the same DataSet three times instead of three different DataTables and giving at each fill a different name for each table created.

Answer (score 0):

But, don't you see that *dataSet.Tables.Add()* call actually creates new DataTable instance, and trying to set its TableName property to "test1 " (btw. take care, space is not allowed in TableName).

That newly created instance(s) are set to properties *dataTabletest1...3* - so, you lose access to the original ones, initially populated with data from the database.

You should do something like this:

```
  DataTable dataTabletest1 = dataSet.Tables.Add("Test1");
  DataTable dataTabletest2 = dataSet.Tables.Add("Test2");
  DataTable dataTabletest3 = dataSet.Tables.Add("Test3");

  dataAdaptertest1.Fill(dataTabletest1);
  dataAdaptertest2.Fill(dataTabletest2);
  dataAdaptertest3.Fill(dataTabletest3);
```

Please, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-a-datatable-to-a-dataset